# Propel model:build gives dos not creating model files with no notices or errors

Tags: php, propel

Iam trying to generate model files using Propel ORM. I went through all the steps of installation using Composer. Then in Terminal i executed

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ nick$ cd testproject
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:testproject nick$ vendor/bin/propel
```

and i get the version details easily, but funny enough this only works the first time. After i close off my terminal and try to execute the commands above, terminal simply moves on to the command input prompt and nothing happens. And to make things even weirder for me (as a beginner to Propel), at this point any junk i pass as parameters to propel will have the same effect of not producing any response and asking for the next command to execute (as if the first one was successful).

Soo I get

```
 admins-MacBook-Pro-2:testproject nick$ vendor/bin/propel
 admins-MacBook-Pro-2:testproject nick$ _
```

even if i pass in junk data i get

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:testproject nick$ vendor/bin/propel junk
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:testproject nick$ _
```

**Hence**

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:testproject nick$ vendor/bin/propel model:build
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:testproject nick$ _
```

Directory Structure

```
-testproject(Folder)
 - composer.json
 - composer.lock
 - index.php
 - **propel.php**
 - **schema.xml**(generated by propel it self using reverse)
 - vendor(Folder)
```

Also not I am on a Mac and i had exactly the same problem yesterday on Windows  Command Prompt.
Searched all over for this and seems like Propel has close to NO Tutorials on we (obviously except the documentation which i went through over and over to make sure i did not miss something);

And Propel Community seems so small, should i just drop it for an ORM with a bigger community.

Answer (score 1):

The verbosity option is your friend.

First off export your path so you only need to type `propel`

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/where/ever/you/installed/propel/bin/propel
```

Throw that in your .bash_rc to keep it persistent. 
Now let's try:

```
propel model:build --verbose
```

Don't forget to convert config.
you can read the rest [in the dox](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#building-the-model)

Answer (score 0):

The most seems like your binary is just not executed. Try to execute explicitly:

```
php vendor/bin/propel
```

Comment: Its `php vendor/propel/propel/bin/propel.php build:om` to be exact :-)

Comment: @DarkBee, what you talking about? If propel installed properly by composer, my string will work fine. But your seems weird — haven't seen `build:om` command ever.

Comment: So if i run it with **php** at the beginning, only get  

`SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../propel/propel/bin"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/propel"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"`

Comment: Oh well..not a good start to this propel relationship...best to end it now..and try Doctrine.....its not propel its me :P